# boolean evaluation c++ asm code

Tags: assembly, x86, boolean

I am currently testing various codelines to enrich my knowledge in Assembly (X86, specifically now) and using MS VC++.
I am clueless regarding how the machine generates different parts of the code compared to other compilers (gcc)

I've come across a boolean evalution line, which resulted in the following ASM code:

```
void boolean_literals() {
    /*true/false*/

01133A2E C6 45 FB 01          mov         byte ptr [b],1  
    bool b = 6 == 6; 
01133A32 0F B6 45 FB          movzx       eax,byte ptr [b]  
01133A36 85 C0                test        eax,eax  
01133A38 74 04                je          boolean_literals+2Eh (01133A3Eh)  
    if (b) {
01133A3A C6 45 FB 00          mov         byte ptr [b],0  
        b = false;
    }
```

The thing is - I can't actually see the boolean evaluation in ASM:

```
mov         byte ptr [b],1
```

Any compilers option that might solve this or w/e ?
:)

Comment: The Boolean evaluation is the `TEST` instruction. It sets the zero flag if the result is zero, and the following `JE` instruction (equivalent to `JZ`) jumps if the zero flag is set. That said, you must be looking at code generated by the compiler when optimizations are disabled, which is a big waste of time. You'll see a lot of unusual and sub-optimal sequences that don't mirror either what an assembly programmer would actually write *or* what you'd see in the real-world when disassembling code.

Comment: `6 == 6` is evaluated at compile time, and the code is then compiled as if it were `bool b = true;`. If you enable optimizations, the compiler will likely collapse the whole fragment to `bool b = false;`

Comment: Thank you, Igor & Cody. I stambled upon what Igor presented, I guess it is evaluated at compile time. I just wanted to see the boolean logic behind it

Answer (score 0):

The boolean evaluation is here:

```
test        eax,eax  
je          boolean_literals+2Eh (01133A3Eh)
```

`Test` performs: `flags = eax and eax` which will set `ZF=1 if eax == 0`.
The `je` will jump on `ZF=1` thereby completing the boolean test.

If you enable optimizations, the compiler will most likely <kbd>`:-)`</kbd> find that the result of your test is always true, and will thus dispense with the test altogether. In which case the following code is all that is needed.

```
mov         byte ptr [b],1    //b = true
```